# Python code hanging. Same logic was used in C++ and worked fine

Tags: python, matplotlib

I ran the same logic using the while loops (without matplotlib obviously) in C++ and outputted my coordinates perfectly. When I use python it just hangs. I have never seen this happen before. I am kind of at a lose because there is no errors to go off of. I usually do my logic in C++ so maybe I am going about this wrong in python? Not sure. Any ideas?

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

variable924 = 0.0
variable921 = .0025
variable922 = .0450
variable923 = 5.0 + variable924
variable920 = 0
variable925 = 0
variable926 = 0
passes = 1
incpasses = passes
r = 0
degrees = 0

z = []
x = []
y = []

while (variable920 < 65):      
    variable925 = (1.0010-math.cos(variable920*(math.pi/180.00)))*variable922
    variable926 = (math.sin(variable920*(math.pi/180.00))-variable922)
    r = variable925 + variable921
    while (incpasses >= 1):
        xSet = (-variable926/passes)
        while (degrees <= 360):
            ySet = (math.sin(degrees * (math.pi / 180.00)))*r
            zSet = (math.cos(degrees * (math.pi / 180.00)))*r
            degrees = degrees + 30
            x.append(xSet)
            y.append(ySet)
            z.append(zSet)
        incpasses = incpasses - 1
        degrees = 0
incpasses = passes
variable920 = variable920 + variable923

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: You are not incrementing `variable920` in your outermost `while` loop, and therefore that loop will never terminate. Perhaps you should check your indentation for the line `incpasses = passes` and the line after that?

Comment: Ahh yea. I just needed to indent incpasses = passes and the line just below it to increment it. I thought they were in the loop. I am not sure how to vote you as best answer, but you deserve it. @senshin

Answer (score 0):

Eh, sure, I'll make this an answer.

You just had your indentation wrong. The outermost `while` loop has a condition based on `variable920`, but `variable920` never changes in the loop. This is presumably an indentation issue in the code you posted. By indenting the following lines one level:

```
incpasses = passes
variable920 = variable920 + variable923
```

you move the increment of `variable920` into the body of the outermost `while` loop, thus allowing that loop to terminate.

---

In future situations with non-halting loops, you might find it helpful to include sentinel `print` statements to print the value of the variable in the loop condition (if any), so you can see how the variable is changing (or not changing) over the course of the loops.

Comment: or use a debugger instead of putting `print` statements